# Can we get a migration path opened to math.SE?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

Update from Manishearth: Now that migration to Math.SE seems to be reasonably high, I'm bumping this to see if we can get the migration path now.

One for the SE team: can we get an official migration path for moving questions from physics.SE to math.SE? A non-negligible fraction of the off-topic questions we get here are purely mathematical in nature and mbq or I wind up moving them to the math site.

Current stats (26 June, 2013):

In the past 90 days, 25 questions have been migrated from Phy.SE to Math.SE, with a 4% rejection rate (that's [1 rejected migration](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60331/what-does-the-following-statement-mean))

Could we have this now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is done. The volume of migrations isn't *huge*, but there are enough of them to demonstrate a reasonable amount of overlap - so, no need to have to bother the moderators about this.

[image: the migrate to math.se option]

Comment: Thanks Shog9, now we have a Rosen-Einstein bridge to Math SE ha ha :-)

Comment: Yay! _happy dance_ Thanks for looking in to this!

Answer (score 11):

Here is an incomplete list of questions that have been migrated:

- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6034/vector-multiplication-with-scalars
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5987/derivation-of-the-method-of-lagrange-multipliers
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5694/prove-that-honeycomb-structures-are-the-most-geometrically-efficient-structure
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5391/derivation-of-fourier-series
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4714/what-is-the-current-status-of-vinay-deolalikars-proof-that-p-is-not-equal-to-np
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11976/fractal-dimension-after-nonlinear-transformation

This question probably would have been migrated if we had the migration path open, as it was closed by 5 community votes, but as it is I had to reopen it and migrate it

- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66468/uniqueness-of-the-vector-in-mathbbrn-specified-by-the-curl-divergence-and

Also

- [Vector product in 2 dimensions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4626/vector-product-in-2-dimensions)

could have been migrated, but as I recall it's so basic we figured it wasn't worth it, or something like that.

Feel free to edit in additional examples.

Answer (score 3):

In order to open up a migration path, we'd first like to see evidence that a significant number of closed questions have been manually migrated by moderators or should be migrated to the destination site.

Perhaps you / the community can create an answer here that points to a lot of examples.

Comment: Sure, I created a list of examples in another answer.