# Additional choices for migration

Tags: feature-request, flagging, migration

> Related: [Can we get a migration path opened to math.SE?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/507/can-we-get-a-migration-path-opened-to-math-se)

When we close **or** flag a question as *off-topic*, we have an option called `belongs to meta.physics.SE`. We're also receiving questions that belong to Math.SE or Electronics.SE most of the time. So, it'd be easy for migration if there is a choice for `belongs to Math.SE` and `belongs to Electronics.SE`. Well, other sites do have that option.

For instance, we can take Android.SE. It's having a choice for `belongs to SO`. I think superuser is also having such an option.

[image]

Comment: This we can probably have. We are allowed up to five migration targets. I'd like to see Scientific Computation as well, but I don't think they put beta sites on the list.

Comment: The five migration targets should be chosen by experienced volume of migrated questions until now. The last 90 days indicates (in decending order): 1. Math, 2. SciComp, 3. Chem, 4. EE, 5. Bio.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC we need to display a major need for such a closing path. Currently, we don't even have enough active close voters, so mods have to intervene in migrations anyway. Also, we get ~one migration every day on average. That's not much. I don't think that's enough to convince SE to give us the migration paths.

However, if we *were*  to get migration paths, I'd suggest Math, SciComp, EE, and Academia. Maybe not Academia. Nobody on Physics has managed to decipher their FAQ, so it's better to leave it out of the fray.

Here's a snapshot of the migration stats ([link for 10k users](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats)):

[image]

Comment: ~ 1 per day... You say *"that's not much"*. But, it's far enough. Like I've said, Math & EE is in the first place. If you require additional info, I've checked out android. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/100vJAv.jpg) are the stats for 90 days. They've got only 24 migrations to SO. `6` is not a big difference. I think you get the point ;-)

Comment: @crazy I think they had the migration path from the start. Also, my point about us not having enough close voters still applies.

Comment: Yeah... To that point - I've got nothing to say ;-)