# Why can't I suggest "Chemistry Stack Exchange" as another site when flagging a question as off-topic?

Tags: feature-request, flagging, migration

I've recently noticed that when I flag something as off-topic by suggesting it to another site(in order to get better answers for that question) I only see the options of Physics Meta Stack Exchange and Mathematics Stack Exchange (shown below in the picture), like no Chemistry Stack Exchange or Biology Stack Exchange.

I was wondering if the coding or suggestion could be fixed somehow to incorporate more science sites. I understand that mathematics questions are the most cross-posted in the Physics Stack exchange but I do believe I've often seen many good chemistry and biology questions end up here which could've been better answered in their respective sites(especially posted by new users). Hence my suggestion for this improvement. Maybe add a search feature like when adding "duplicates" to **link** another stack exchange site?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4144/2451 , https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4869/2451 , https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5690/2451 ,   https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10231/2451

Comment: @Blue I'd also add, don't migrate questions which are on topic here.

Comment: Indeed, [it is very close](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/435:_Purity).