# Does this type of question violate the rules?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: [Commutation and Sharing Same Eigenvalues](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/595401/)

Comment: It is certainly a mathematics question not a physics one.

Comment: It is related to the quantum mechanics, so that's why I post it to the physics forum. But I will be more carefull in the future thanks.

Comment: I understand you're probably asking it in the context of quantum mechanics but the topic is just on the properties of general Hilbert space operators.

Comment: Okey, thanks. I appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7140/149907, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5713/149907

Comment: It already does not. :-) (Was migrated by community.)