# Protocols for migration of questions between different Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

I'm a bit confused about why [this QM question was migrated from PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/802005/revisions) to [this question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4865565/). I believe the more appropriate forum for this specific *mathematical-physics question* is [PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour). Could someone please shed some light on how the migration decisions are made and if question-authors' decisions for choosing a specific SE site to post questions are taken into account.

> This question was migrated to Mathematics Stack Exchange (MSE) because it can be answered by people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields. Migrated 9 hours ago by Miyase, ZeroTheHero, Hyperon.

Comment: Three users voted to migrate it, so it was migrated.

Comment: *if question-authors' decisions for choosing a specific SE forum to post questions are taken into account* No. The OP’s opinion on suitability is no more important than any other user’s opinion on suitability.

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14633/25301

Comment: See also https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5713/25301, which I mentioned in the other linked answer.

Comment: Also, SE sites are not forums, they are simply Q&A sites.

Comment: The short version is that for pre-defined migration paths (such as to math), it takes three users to migrate the question who want it migrated. Even if a majority of users here would like to see the question here (not saying it is the case for the specific question), there is no way to keep it here. This is a problematic aspect about pre-defined migration paths, which has been discussed here before.

Answer (score 4):

That one’s easy: it’s a math question.  There is no physics (at all) attached to the question.  True, the SvN theorem is used in physics, but this doesn’t make every SvN question a physics question, no more than a question on unitary groups is automatically a physics question.

If the premise was a physics problem and the question presented on that premise, then it might very well be a physics question, but this is not the case here.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question.